# Highcharts - Line breaks from node to node in sankey diagram

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I got problem when try connect nodes in opposite direction, to get loop.

How can i configure line that connects "Alpha","Beta","Gamma" and "Page views" not to break?
[image]

Here is my code: 
   jsfiddle.net/Hideon/n6Lqutch/4/

I want make something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please refer the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guide for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you any direct advices how to improve my question?

Comment: Hi Андрей Ефременков, very useful in your case would to provide your code and some mockup with wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting points backwards is not fully supported in Highcharts `sankey` series yet.

This problem is reported on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8218

For now, the workaround is to set right `marginBottom` and `clip` to false:

```
chart: {
    marginLeft: 50,
    marginRight: 50,
    marginBottom: 100
},

series: [{
    clip: false,
    ...
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t3jLszqy/

API:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginBottom

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.clip